# After calling ACTION_REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS app is still optimized

Tags: android

I am calling the `Settings.ACTION_REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS` intent as described in https://commonsware.com/blog/2015/11/11/google-anti-trust-issues.html

The dialog is fired and I choose `YES`. But if I go to "Battery optimization" setting, the app is not in the list, it doesn't seem that the battery optimization was disabled for the app  (the list displays by default the "Not optimized" apps):

[image]

And if I choose "All apps" from the drop-down, I can see the app in the list and it has "Optimizing battery use".

I am confused. After choosing "YES" in the dialog showed by `Settings.ACTION_REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS` shouldn't the battery optimization be disabled for the app?

I am on Android 6, Samsung Galaxy A5 (2016).

Also, what's strange is that the `isIgnoringBatteryOptimizations` is returning `true`. How come this returns `true` but the app is not the "Not optimized" list?

Comment: Just to be sure, swipe the Settings app off the overview screen and reopen it, to make sure that you are looking at the latest-and-greatest battery optimization settings.

Comment: And, FWIW, `startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS, Uri.parse("package:"+getPackageName())));` is working just fine on a Nexus 7 (2013) running Android 6.0.1.

Comment: arhhhh I think you are right, it must had been a refresh issue, albeit I could swear it was not.

Comment: Do you know, does Google still bans apps which call this? I have an app which greatly depends on GPS tracking.

Comment: "does Google still bans apps which call this?" -- I have no idea, sorry.

Comment: Thank you a lot again. I wish you could add an answer to mark this as resolved.

Comment: I recommend that you answer your own question, as you know what you did better than I do. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per's @CommonsWare answer (isn't he awesome?) in the comments, it actually looks like Settings app has a refresh issue. It doesn't refresh the status accordingly. I must swipe app off screen and restart it to see updated status.